# Appending the Content of a div to a form using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, yii2, append

i have a select form element inside a div and i want to append the content of that div (select Element) to my form.
i tried the code below and its appending very well but the select becomes inactive and the on-change event is no longer working.
Any help will be greatly appreciated Thanks.

```
//JAVASCRIPT CODE getting the div//
function getList(serial){
       return document.getElementById('selecter').outterHtml;
}
//Div Containing the SelectElement//
    <div id="selecter">

<?php
    $data = Arrayhelper::map(Goods::find()->all(), 'p_code', 'name');
// without model
echo Select2::widget([
    'name' => 'p_name[]',
    'data' => $data,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Prroduct ...',
    'class'=>'form-control',
    'onchange'=>'
                    $.post( "index.php?r=goods/list&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function(data){
                    document.getElementById("eset").value = data;
                    });'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]);?>
</div>
//End of Div//
onclick calls the getList function
```

Comment: outterHtml should be `outerHTML` and your js function should be within script tags if it isn't

Comment: Thanks for your swift respond. sorry for the spelling error, is was actually outerHtml and yes it within a script tag... its just the content of the select element that doesn't work but it will display whenever the getList function is called @pete

Comment: Can you post a more complete example? Your code post the user choice somewhere, set something not present with id eset to the response and dont do anything else.

Comment: the variable "$data = Arrayhelper::map(Goods::find()->all(), 'p_code', 'name');"...map to my database table called goods which contains name and product_code.. which is what suppose to be populated in the dropdown list whenever its been called...the rest of the code are bulky and irrelevant

Comment: your question is confusing you are trying to append a pre-populated `select2` into another div ? is that correct?

Comment: yes 
the pre populated dropdown is a yii slelect2 widget that comes with a search box.

Comment: this the code for the select element that is populated by database data <?php
 $sel="Select2::widget([
    'name' => 'p_name[]',
    'data' => Arrayhelper::map(Goods::find()->all(), 'p_code', 'name'),
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Prroduct ...',
 'class'=>'form-control',
 'onchange'=>'
                    $.post( \"index.php?r=goods/list&id='.'\"+$(this).val(), function(data){
                    document.getElementById(\"eset\").value = data;
                    });'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]);";?>